# Two different login pages for one model with devise on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am working on an rails app in which there is one table **Users**, which has two roles Admin and member. Until now I am using single login page.

But now, I need to make two different login pages with completely different styling for admin and member.
Moreover Admin don't have sign_up option but member has.

I am totally confused that is it possible or not?
If possible, how to achieve this.

Comment: If you do `rails generate devise:views` you will be able to see the devise templates. You could duplicate the sign in view and rename it as admin, you can customize what form items are displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devise sign in form is just a form with action matching to devise controller.

You can write this form code anywhere you like,

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => session_path(:user)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
  <%= f.label :remember_me %>
  <%= f.submit 'Sign in' %>
  <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(:user) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: and what to pass it from controller, user= User.new , ?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @maximus answer, you could use the `Pundit` gem to define your logged in `:user` action through a `UserPolicy` controller.  Within this controller, you should be able to define which direction a passed in User navigates to defined by their logged in `role`.

https://github.com/elabs/pundit